# Limiting maximum number of connections to server not working

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I have built a client-server program using C socket programming and its run perfectly on my Ubuntu OS which runs on a VMware . The only problem I have is with the [listen](http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c/) API call .

Though i have set the connection limit to 2 , I can open four terminals and connect to the server at the same time .

```
 listen (serverFd, 2); /* Maximum pending connection length */
```

The client and the server runs on the same computer .

This is the snippet of the code

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>       /* for sockaddr_un struct */
#define DEFAULT_PROTOCOL   0
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024


/* POSIX renames "Unix domain" as "local IPC."
    Not all systems define AF_LOCAL and PF_LOCAL (yet). */
#ifndef AF_LOCAL
#define AF_LOCAL    AF_UNIX
#endif
#ifndef PF_LOCAL
#define PF_LOCAL    PF_UNIX
#endif


/****************************************************************/
main ()
{

    printf("Hello, server is starting...\n");

    // initialize data from text file into system
    readData();

    printf("Country data loaded with total of %i countries available.\n", NoOfRecordsRead);

    if(NoOfRecordsRead == 0)
    {
        printf("No valid data to serve, terminating application...\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    int serverFd, clientFd, serverLen, clientLen;
    struct sockaddr_un serverAddress;/* Server address */
    struct sockaddr_un clientAddress; /* Client address */
    struct sockaddr* serverSockAddrPtr; /* Ptr to server address */
    struct sockaddr* clientSockAddrPtr; /* Ptr to client address */

    /* Ignore death-of-child signals to prevent zombies */
    signal (SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

    serverSockAddrPtr = (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddress;
    serverLen = sizeof (serverAddress);

    clientSockAddrPtr = (struct sockaddr*) &clientAddress;
    clientLen = sizeof (clientAddress);

    /* Create a socket, bidirectional, default protocol */
    serverFd = socket (AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    serverAddress.sun_family = AF_LOCAL; /* Set domain type */
    strcpy (serverAddress.sun_path, "country"); /* Set name */
    unlink ("country"); /* Remove file if it already exists */
    bind (serverFd, serverSockAddrPtr, serverLen); /* Create file */
    listen (serverFd, 2); /* Maximum pending connection length */

    printf("Server started.\n");

    while (1) /* Loop forever */
    {
        /* Accept a client connection */
        clientFd = accept (serverFd, clientSockAddrPtr, &clientLen);

        if (fork () == 0) /* Create child to send recipe */
        {
                 //do something

        }

    }

}
```

**Why is this happening**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Though i have set the connection limit to 2

Nope. You've set the listen *backlog* to 2. Read the documentation on the listen command:

> The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the queue of pending connections for sockfd may grow.  If  a  connection
>         request  arrives when the queue is full, the client may receive an error with an indication of ECONNREFUSED or, if the underlying
>         protocol supports retransmission, the request may be ignored so that a later reattempt at connection succeeds.

Your program can decide not to call `accept()` if you want to limit the number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: +1 And the platform can silently adjust the backlog value down or more usually up.